# why onclick dont works on expandable recyclerview

Tags: android-studio

Sorry if i pasted all the code but it shows no error and i dont know what to do

## MainActivity.java

```
package it.unich.s3221238.recycleapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewInterface {

    GG_RecyclerViewAdapter myAdapter;
    ArrayList<Parent_rec> parentGiochiArrayList;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Child_rec>> childGiochiArrayList; // Aggiornamento del tipo

    RecyclerView RVparent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RVparent = findViewById(R.id.RVparent);

        String[] nomeGenere = {"RPG", "Sport", "Platform", "RogueLike"};
        String[][] nomeGioco = {
                {"World Of Warcraft", "Skyrim", "Dark Souls", "Mass Effect"},
                {"FIFA", "NBA 2K", "Madden NFL", "WWE 2K"},
                {"Crash Bandicoot", "Celeste", "Limbo", "Inside"},
                {"Risk of Rain 2", "Darkest Dungeon", "Slay the Spire", "Spelunky"}
        };
        int[][] imageIDs = {
                {R.drawable.wow_icon, R.drawable.skyrim, R.drawable.darkss, R.drawable.masseff},
                {R.drawable.fifa, R.drawable.nba, R.drawable.madden, R.drawable.wwe},
                {R.drawable.crashb, R.drawable.celeste, R.drawable.skyrim, R.drawable.inside},
                {R.drawable.risk, R.drawable.dungeon, R.drawable.slay, R.drawable.spelun}
        };

        int[] imageIDCollapsed = {R.drawable.wow_icon, R.drawable.fifa, R.drawable.crashb, R.drawable.risk};
        int[] imageIDExpanded = {R.drawable.rpg, R.drawable.sport, R.drawable.platf, R.drawable.rogue};

        parentGiochiArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        childGiochiArrayList = new ArrayList<>(); // Inizializzazione

        for (int i = 0; i < nomeGenere.length; i++) {
            Parent_rec parentRec = new Parent_rec(nomeGenere[i], String.valueOf(i + 1), imageIDs[i][0], imageIDCollapsed[i], imageIDExpanded[i]);
            parentGiochiArrayList.add(parentRec);

            ArrayList<Child_rec> giochi = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < nomeGioco[i].length; j++) {
                Child_rec childRec = new Child_rec(nomeGioco[i][j], String.valueOf(j + 1), imageIDs[i][j]);
                giochi.add(childRec);
            }
            childGiochiArrayList.add(giochi);
        }

        myAdapter = new GG_RecyclerViewAdapter(this, parentGiochiArrayList, childGiochiArrayList, this);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        RVparent.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        RVparent.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
        Parent_rec clickedParent = parentGiochiArrayList.get(position);
        ArrayList<Child_rec> clickedChildGames = childGiochiArrayList.get(position);

        String nomeGenereCliccato = clickedParent.getNomeGenere();
        String accessCliccato = clickedParent.getAccess();
        int imageIDCliccata = clickedParent.getImage();

        ArrayList<String> nomiGiochi = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> costiGiochi = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> imageIDsGiochi = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Child_rec child : clickedChildGames) {
            nomiGiochi.add(child.getnomeGioco());
            costiGiochi.add(child.getCosto());
            imageIDsGiochi.add(child.getImage());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("nomeGenere", nomeGenereCliccato);
        intent.putExtra("access", accessCliccato);
        intent.putExtra("imageID", imageIDCliccata);
        intent.putExtra("imageIDCollapsed", clickedParent.getImageIDCollapsed());
        intent.putExtra("imageIDExpanded", clickedParent.getImageIDExpanded());
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("nomiGiochi", nomiGiochi);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("costiGiochi", costiGiochi);
        intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("imageIDsGiochi", imageIDsGiochi);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

## MainActivity2

```
package it.unich.s3221238.recycleapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        // Ricevere i dati passati dall'attività precedente tramite l'Intent
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String nomeGenere = extras.getString("nomeGenere");
            String access = extras.getString("access");
            int imageID = extras.getInt("imageID");
            int imageIDCollapsed = extras.getInt("imageIDCollapsed");
            int imageIDExpanded = extras.getInt("imageIDExpanded");
            ArrayList<String> nomiGiochi = extras.getStringArrayList("nomiGiochi");
            ArrayList<String> costiGiochi = extras.getStringArrayList("costiGiochi");
            ArrayList<Integer> imageIDsGiochi = extras.getIntegerArrayList("imageIDsGiochi");

            // Visualizzare le informazioni ricevute nell'UI della tua attività
            TextView textViewNomeGenere = findViewById(R.id.textViewNomeGenere);
            TextView textViewAccess = findViewById(R.id.textViewAccess);
            ImageView imageViewGenere = findViewById(R.id.imageViewGenere);

            // Mostrare le informazioni del genere
            textViewNomeGenere.setText(nomeGenere);
            textViewAccess.setText(access);
            imageViewGenere.setImageResource(imageID);


        }
    }
}
```

## AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/nomeGioco"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Recycleapp"
        tools:targetApi="31">

        <activity
            android:name=".splash"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity2"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

## Child_rec

```
package it.unich.s3221238.recycleapp;

public class Child_rec {

    String nomeGioco,costo;
    int imageIDC;

    public Child_rec(String nomeGioco, String costo, int imageID) {
        this.nomeGioco = nomeGioco;
        this.costo = costo;
        this.imageIDC = imageID;
    }
    public String getnomeGioco() {
        return nomeGioco;
    }

    public String getCosto() {
        return costo;
    }

    public int getImage() {
        return imageIDC;
    }
}
```

## ChildAdapter

```
package it.unich.s3221238.recycleapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChildAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChildAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<Child_rec> childGiochiArrayList;

    public ChildAdapter(ArrayList<Child_rec> childGiochiArrayList) {
        this.childGiochiArrayList = childGiochiArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_recycler,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Child_rec childRec = childGiochiArrayList.get(position);

        holder.tvNomegioco.setText(childRec.nomeGioco);
        holder.tvCosto.setText(childRec.costo);
        holder.ivChild.setImageResource(childRec.imageIDC);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return childGiochiArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView tvNomegioco, tvCosto;
        ImageView ivChild;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvNomegioco = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
            tvCosto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            ivChild = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

## GG_RecyclerViewAdapter

```
package it.unich.s3221238.recycleapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GG_RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GG_RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private final RecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface;

    private Activity activity;
    ArrayList<Parent_rec> parentGiochiArrayList;
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Child_rec>> childGiochiArrayList; // Aggiornamento del tipo

    public GG_RecyclerViewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Parent_rec> parGiochi, ArrayList<ArrayList<Child_rec>> childGiochi,
                                  RecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.parentGiochiArrayList = parGiochi;
        this.childGiochiArrayList = childGiochi;
        this.recyclerViewInterface = recyclerViewInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GG_RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_row,parent,false);
        return new GG_RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder(view, recyclerViewInterface);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Parent_rec parentRec = parentGiochiArrayList.get(position);

        holder.tvGenere.setText(parentRec.nomeGenere);
        holder.tvAcess.setText(parentRec.access);

        // Aggiornamento dell'immagine in base allo stato espanso/ridotto
        if (parentRec.isExpandable()) {
            // Immagine per lo stato espanso
            holder.ImageView.setImageResource(parentRec.imageIDExpanded);
        } else {
            // Immagine per lo stato ridotto
            holder.ImageView.setImageResource(parentRec.imageID);
        }

        ChildAdapter childAdapter = new ChildAdapter(childGiochiArrayList.get(position));
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
        holder.nested_rv.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        holder.nested_rv.setAdapter(childAdapter);

        boolean isExpandable = parentRec.isExpandable();
        holder.nested_rv.setVisibility(isExpandable ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        holder.idlayoutp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                parentRec.setExpandable(!parentRec.isExpandable());
                notifyItemChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return parentGiochiArrayList.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView ImageView;
        TextView tvGenere, tvAcess;
        RecyclerView nested_rv;
        RelativeLayout idlayoutp;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, RecyclerViewInterface recyclerViewInterface) {
            super(itemView);
            tvGenere = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tvAcess = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            nested_rv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nested_rv);
            idlayoutp = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idlayoutp);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (recyclerViewInterface != null) {
                        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            recyclerViewInterface.onItemClick(pos);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

## RecyclerViewInterface

```
package it.unich.s3221238.recycleapp;

public interface RecyclerViewInterface {
    void onItemClick(int position);

}
```

The goal was to achieve an expandable RecyclerView that, when clicked, takes you to 'activity_main2', but it's not working, and I don't know why. The code doesn't throw any errors.